# JQuery Plugin - Highlighting a content editable box that contains a certain word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Here is the HTML/CSS - https://jsfiddle.net/toalhea/y6hns5tr/1/

I'm trying to create a jquery plugin for an assignment that would highlight either the word or the box that contains the word 'burger'.

I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript and just lost on understanding how to do this. It was suggested to use innerhtml or innertext. Any help is appreciated.

```
(function($) {

   $.fn.highlightword = function () {
      this.css( "background", "yellow" ); 
            
      }
   }

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3",
   });
   $('[contentEditable="true"]').on('click', function () {
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow")
      $(this).blur(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "white")
      })
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin:auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 {
    border: 1px solid #012361;
    width: 15%;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
  }
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }

h2 {
      display: inline;
      margin-right: 6em;
    }
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
#sortable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#sortable ul {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Menu-Sortable</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
        rel = "stylesheet">
        <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.highlight-word.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      </head>


    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Sort the menu items to their appropriate header or rename the items to fit the category.</h1>
            <h2>Appetizer</h2> <h2>Main Course</h2><h2>Dessert</h2> <br><br>
        <div id="sortable">
            <ul id="sortable1">
                <li contenteditable="true"> Mozzerella Sticks</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Brisket Nachos</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Quesadillas</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Salsa and Chips</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Queso and Chips</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Brisket Mac & Cheese</li>
            </ul> 

            <ul id="sortable2">
                <li contenteditable="true"> SouthWest Burger</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Hawaiian Burger<li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Cannoli</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Beef Brisket Sandwhich</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Turkey Club Sandwhich</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Lemon Souffles</li>
            </ul> 

            <ul id="sortable3">
                <li contenteditable="true"> Wonton Tacos</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Molten Chocolate Lava Cake</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> English Custard</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Queso Burger</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Chocolate Chip Panookies</li>
                <li contenteditable="true"> Frozen Hot Chocolate</li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```